# override constructor c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

I have abstract class A

```
class A{
 public:
  A(dim) : dim_(dim);
 private:
  int dim_;
}
```

and class B

```
class B : public A{
 public:
  B(int dim);
}
```

and I need to make constructor for class B, which works only when dim > 1 and throw assertions otherwise.

in this case

```
B::B(int dim) : A(dim){
  assert(dim > 1);
}
```

it works, but it's not good solution I think, because instance of the class A was created and deleted.

Than I make init-method for class A:

```
class A{
 public:
  void init(int dim){
    dim_ = dim;
  }
  A(int dim){
    init(dim);
  }
 private:
  int dim_;
}
```

and change constructor of class B:

```
class B : public A {
 public:
  B(int dim){
    assert(dim > 1);
    init(dim);
  }
}
```

but it doesn't work. Is there any possible solutions for my problem?

Comment: class `A` is not _abstract_...

Comment: somehow i get the feeling that relying on 'dim' in your ctor is the wrong approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you could write a small `myint` class which makes sure that the `int` you pass is always greater than `1`:

```
struct myint
{
    int data; 
    myint(int i) : data(i) { assert(data > 1); }
};
```

Now use it in your class:

```
class B : public A{
 public:
  B(myint dim) //this can still take int, due to implicit conversion! 
   : A(dim.data) { }
}
```

Note that you can still construct `B` passing `int`, as it will implicitly convert into `myint` and while the conversion takes place (implicitly), it will test the *assert*, and if that succeeds, only then you would be able to pass `dim.data` to the base class `A`. If the *assert* fails, your program will abort before entering into the base class constructor (without initializing anything in derived class also).

---

You could even generalize it as:

```
//Summary : gint<N> makes sure that data > N
template<int N>
struct gint  //call it greater int
{
    int data; 
    gint(int i) : data(i) { assert(data > N); } //Use N here!
};
```

Now use it in your class:

```
class B : public A{
 public:
  B(gint<1> dim) //the template argument 1 makes sure that dim.data > 1
   : A(dim.data) { }
}
```

If you need another class, for example:

```
class Xyz : public A{
 public:
  B(gint<10> dim)  //gint<10> makes sure that dim.data > 10
   : A(dim.data) { }
}
```

Cool, isn't?

Comment: I have seen companies where there have a policy to always declare single argument constructors as `explicit` and I believe it is for a good reason. Still I believe your solution to the problem is quite cool.

Comment: @izomorphius: Yes, they might have good reasons. But it is not always good. `std::string` has *non-explicit* single argument constructor, and I think it is non-explicit for a good reason.

Comment: It's cool solution. In soviet russia we called such solutions 'Kostyl' (it means "crooked nail" acording to google translate)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make you second option work, you will have to add an empty constructor to `A`. However this will not help you too much because the `A` object is created before you enter the constructor for `B`, thus whether you have an empty constructor or a consturctor that takes an object of type int, you will always construct an object of type `A`.

If A is as simple as you show it in this sample I believe it is not a big deal to constuct it even for invalid dims. If it is more complex I would suggest you create an ampty consturctor for A that initializes as little part of A as possible and then an `init` method to do the more complex stuff.

Comment: And make the empty constructor(which doesn't call init()) protected in order to allow it's usage only in B(int);